# Power BI custom view (like with tableu)

Tags: powerbi

In tableu it is possible to create views for tabs and can select which view as below. Is this possible in Power BI or is the only option to create a separate tab in the power BI dashboard for each view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This ability (as shownon YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bxoYnGkwTM) is not possible in Power BI. If I move around tiles, for example, then that's it. The dashboard has changed. There is no, "*I'd like to save what I'm looking at as a link or tab on this dashboard.*" If you want another view of the same dashboard, then click the 3 dots & hit `save a copy` & do whatever customization you need there instead.